# Multiple OR/AND filter in AWS Amplify GraphQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

with a simple schema like this:

```
type Ticket @model{
  id: ID! @primaryKey
  title: String!
  description: String!
  state: State @default(value: "new")
  priority: Priority
}
enum Priority {
  low
  medium
  high
  emergency
}
enum State {
  new
  pending
  closed
  waiting
  suspended
}
```

How can I filter my query in order to get the tickets that have **priority** equal "low" OR "high" and also **state** equal "new" OR "waiting" for example?

In the [documentation](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql/search-and-result-aggregations/#nested-search-conditions-and-or-not) there is an example for a condition with AND and OR together, but not for multiple OR.

Filters are provided through a JS Object, I can't use multiple **OR** keys in this way for example:

```
let graphQLObject = {
  query: queries.listTickets,
  variables: {
    filter: {
      or: [
        { priority: {eq: "low"} },
        { priority: {eq: "high"} }
      ],
      or: [
        { state: {eq: "new"} },
        { state: {eq: "waiting"} }
      ]
    }
  }
};
await API.graphql(graphQLObject);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can nest your conditions simply like this

```
let graphQLObject = {
  query: queries.listTickets,
  variables: {
    filter: {
      and: [
        {
          or: [{ priority: { eq: 'low' } }, { priority: { eq: 'high' } }],
        },
        { or: [{ state: { eq: 'new' } }, { state: { eq: 'waiting' } }] },
      ],
    },
  },
}
```

Works of course also, if you want to combine multiple AND conditions together with OR etc.